# Certificate Issue with Custom Domain of Web App and Traffic Manager

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

I have created one Web App on Azure and deployed that in two regions. now, using traffic manager I have used failover configuration. As I am having custom domain, I have used individual domains per web app. 
So, each of my web app has 3 domains (I) ... azurewebsites.net (II) ... trafficmanager.net (III) .... mycustomdomain-region1.com
Same for second web app with 3 domains.

As I have correctly configured, my customdomain-region1.com is working without any SSL Certificate error.

But when I use TrafficManager.net based url it is giving me azurewebsites.net certificate error. Why it is check azurewebsites.net even though I am having custom domain and also the certificate is well configured in both the web app.

I have clicked "Continue to this website (not recommended). " and I got Error 404 - Web App not found page

Image attached here...
1) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/685720
2) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/685723

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Image attached here... 
1) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/685720 
2) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/685723

Answer (score 2):

The SSL for *.azurewebsites.net is a shared SSL. If you want to use an SSL for your custom domain you will need to purchase and configure it separately. Info can be found here. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

Note, being you are using multiple web apps in different regions. I would recommend purchasing a wildcard ssl for your domain (*.domain name) and setting up region.websitename.com region2.websitename.com

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Also; make sure the traffic manager is forwarding to your custom domain name, not the azurewebsites.net address.

Comment: Hi Joe, I've a similar issues. I've purchased a custom SSL to applied to my custom domain. How do I make sure the traffic manager is forwarding to your custom domain name? Where do I set that? Below is a sample of the error This server could not prove that it is XXXglobal.trafficmanager.net; its security certificate is from *.XXX.p.azurewebsites.net. Please advise. Thanks.